# Simplifying (and make it more legible) logic condition

Tags: c

I am looking for help in making this logic more legible. Assume each alphabet letter is a compare statement (e.g TRUE == a.foo). Each alphabet is about 30 char long statements.

```
if ( ((a || b)
   && (c || d)) ||
     ((e || f)
   && (g || h)) )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: By putting it all on one line? `if ( ((a || b) && (c || d)) || ((e || f) && (g || h)) )` is IMO more legible.

Comment: It can't be simplified as all of the variables are different. You can just break it into several statements to make it more readable.

Comment: It might help if you can divide the condition into subconditions that have clear names, and use Boolean variables with those names. Then combine the variables.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you. But my situation is each alphabet represents about 30 characters long.

Comment: if you can come up with a good variable name, use `ab = a||b` and so on.

Comment: This isn't really a question about C.

Comment: 'each alphabet represents about 30 characters long' yes, split up into less complex expessions over multiple lines, use temp booleans with meaningful names and, by the look of it, change language from German to something without seemingly endless compound words :)

Comment: It can be helpful to put complicated expressions into functions and giving those functions good names.

Comment: this all is very subjective. For me indentations, based on  parenthesis level sometimes helps. But it tends to go wild sometimes. I also use intermediate variables sometimes. Though it will change evaluation ordering.

Comment: Often, the most important factor in design is not performance, or evaluation ordering, but ease of debugging.  One big compound expression is difficult, many smaller ones with temp booleans is much easier to follow when stepping through with a debugger.  As a general rule, the more 'clever' an expression looks, the more difficult it is to test and debug:(

Comment: You'll save 64 characters in total just by scraping the `TRUE == ` parts, they are just noise anyway. After that you might be able to fit a bit more on a line. Also, check out the `stdbool.h` header, it gives you the standard type `bool` along with the literal values `true` and `false`. No need for homebrew `TRUE`-macro anymore.

Comment: Imagine, if you will, that you are a maintenance engineer, hunting for some obscure bug, and you come across a unit full of complex, compound expressions.  Your first thought: " I'm fu.. full of fear and trepidation ".

Comment: Well, you can also [invert the notation](https://ideone.com/Ans1F9), if you find it more readable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decompose it.

```
int ab = a || b,
    cd = c || d,
    ef = e || f,
    gh = g || h,
    firstThing = ab && cd,
    secondThing = ef && gh;

if (firstThing || secondThing)
```

Comment: This is not the same because of short-circuit. if `a || b` is `0`, `c || d` should not be evaluated. Also if `firstThing` is true, `secondThing` should not be evaluated.

Comment: I assumed they were just side-effect free variable references.

Comment: Decomposition alone won't necessarily cut it, there are expressions that are best understood when they are complete (like `sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)` instead of `xsquare = x*x; ... ; sqrt(sumOfSquares);`) The important part is **abstraction**: The decomposition must serve abstraction to make the code more readable.

Comment: @mch should not , or must not?   Compilers are very clever when optimizing, and are likely to avoid evaluation if it is not necessary.  This can often be seen if you try to follow highly-optimized code with single-steps - the step does not always go where you expect it, (which is why debug builds usually have optimizing off).

Answer (score 4):

Try lining up the subexpressions in groups, lining up the parenthesis:

```
if (((a || b) && (c || d)) || 
    ((e || f) && (g || h)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the conditions to align properly and the logic operator to stand out, I would use this style:

```
if (((a || b) && (c || d))
||  ((e || f) && (g || h))
... 
||  ((u || v) && (w || x))) {
    /* handle the successful test */
} else {
    /* handle the other cases */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few variations of this, but here's one way that I think is pretty clear:

```
if 
( 
    (
        (a || b) 
        && 
        (c || d)
    )
    ||
    (
        (e || f) 
        && 
        (g || h)
    ) 
)
```